# Moving Angular Material out of node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-material

Does anyone know whether it's possible to move my Angular Material framework out of node_modules, after it was at first installed there? If yes, what how to do it and what I should pay attention to?

I tried uninstalling it via npm and putting folder into my assets directory, I changed all paths, but it couldn't find my modules anyway, I was getting `Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'` error. Do I have to change my package.json as well?

My Angular, npm and material versions are all up to date:

- angular-cli : 1.1.1
- angular-material 2.0.0-beta.6
- angular-common-core etc: 4.2.1
- npm: 5.0.3
- node: 8.1.0

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that if I may ask?

Comment: I want to freeze my material version, I don't want it to update.

Comment: then you should define a fixed version of material in your package.json

Comment: I'd like to modify Material's source sass files and then use my bundled version in the project.

Comment: As far as I know, you could change/override material styles through your own styles file. Is not a good idea to change src files

Comment: @Sara If you get this error it's problably because you use a wrong route for your script imports or stylesheet imports. If you can add them in your question

Comment: If you want to lock to a version and make changes, why not fork the project on GitHub and `npm install --save <username>/<repo>`